# Unable to resolve imports from Android Support Repository (Google's Maven included)

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library

In Android Studio 2.3:

app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.test"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

root build.gradle:

```
   buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Result is that support libraries are not resolved although I explicitly added the Google maven repository:

> Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:27.0 ...
>   Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0 ...

Comment: Please add your whole build.gradle code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you have to add the full version code, for example:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0'
```

Notice that I added a last ".0" to the version

Comment: One free beer to you. My concentration is failing after a long night ...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your gradle version, you need to use google() now.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}
```

instead of

```
maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
```

Comment: ... which is true for Android Studio >= 3.